Sending mail through Microsoft 365
I successfully followed the documentation at https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/setup/oauth/#ms-exchange to add an OAuth token (Microsoft 365). At the end of the documentation, it says: "By itself, the access token is inert. To use the token, one must develop or install a suitable extension." How do I use this new connection to Microsoft 365 to send email through Civi? Is this possible / advisable?
I tried just entering my Microsoft 365 credentials in the SMTP Configuration of the Outbound Mail settings, but that didn't work. I feel that I'm missing something.
Thanks!

I don't believe OAuth in CiviCRM currently is supported for outbound email, just inbound (like bounce processing and email-to-activity processing).
